# Change background color of just one page (and all other pages stay the same)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I want to have a blue background on one page of my rails application and all other pages to have a white background. How can I do this? I tried doing

```
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %> or 

<%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>
```

By following [this tutorial](http://theflyingdeveloper.com/controller-specific-assets-with-rails-4/) but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on way of doing this is rendering a different layout on that page

on your controller

```
  def something
    render :layout => 'new_layout'
  end
```

you can also pass a yeald block to over right the css on that pge

in your layout file

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag %>
<%= yield(:head) %>
```

on the view you want to update

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #b0c4de;
    } 
  </style>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add class to body according to controller

In Layout File,

```
<body class="<%= params[:controller]%>">
```

In CSS,

```
body.controller_name {background-color : blue;}
```